# How to model the unknown in data science

Tags: machine-learning-model

I have been asked this question in interview which I was not sure how to respond.

Situation: My company provides personal loans where consumer income is minimum $10,000 per annum and we have data to analyze the default/ delinquency history of these customers.

Problem: is that if my CEO wants the benchmark reduced to $5,000 - what tools should I use to analyze the impact of reducing threshold on default / delinquency?